# Unable to build Maven project

Tags: maven, build

Hi I am getting this error while creating a maven project, can any one help please.

Steps-> Create a Java project -> right click and select Configure -> Convert to Maven project

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Test'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this in Eclipse?  If so check your Maven installation preferences under "Window - Preferences - Maven - Installation".  To match the behaviour of running maven from the command line, you should add your external maven installation here.